# Mobaxterm share clipboard with host?

Tags: ssh, vnc, mobaxterm

Is there a way of copying and pasting between the host and the remote machine when using Mobaxterm? For example, I want to copy some text from the Windows host that I'm running Mobaxterm on, and paste it into a file which I have open in a Mobaxterm VNC or SSH session to a Ubuntu machine.

Comment: Have in the settings of Mobaxterm set "Clipboard" to "enabled"? Perhaps see also "Redirect clipboard"

Comment: I don't see a "Clipboard" setting anywhere in Mobaxterm - only a "Paste using right-click" option, which I have enabled ???

Comment: The [documentation](https://mobaxterm.mobatek.net/documentation.html) shows "clipboard" in *Global > X11*; "Redirect clipboard" is in *Rdp*. I'm not using Mobaxterm, so cannot give precise directions to where are these settings, but perhaps see [Mobaxterm Configuration](https://jhpce.jhu.edu/knowledge-base/mobaxterm-configuration/).

Comment: I can only assume that you are talking about an X11 app?  You didn't specify and although it seems dumb to need to, it would help people help you.

Comment: I'm referring to both VNC (which is an X11 app?) and SSH. The clipboard option was already enabled in x11 settings (thanks for directing me to that - I missed it), but it is not sharing the clipboard between Mobaxterm VNC sessions and the Windows host. Strangely, I have noticed that the clipboard is being shared between my Mobaxterm VNC sessions and a Virtualbox Guest VM which I have running....????